# PHP Page reference check from multiple URLs

Tags: php, database, reference

I have a php script that limits the amount of times people can download content on my site.  I found this script by google searching and changed it a bit to get it working for me.

The problem is I don't know anything really about php.  The first part of the script checks the referring page. When I copied the php script, it was set up to check a single URL.  My problem is I want to reference the php script from multiple pages, because one page has flash on it, and another page I created for mobile phones that don't have flash.  Because of this, the link only works on one page - the page with the url I replace in the script.

My question is, what is the code to include multiple URLs in the reference check?  I don't know if it's something very simple, or if it's even possible.

Below is the part of the php script which checks the referring URL, and then proceeds to login to mySQL DB to begin the download.

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$keymatch= $_SESSION['key'];
$pass='key';
$md5value= md5($pass);

if (($referer=="my url containing php script link")&& ($keymatch==$md5value)) {

$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "host";
$database = "database";
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$selected = mysql_select_db($database,$dbhandle)
or die("Could not select $database");
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

-Richard

Comment: "The problem is I don't know anything really about php." --- this is a community to help developers, not to do your work for you. So either hire someone to do your work, or *learn* how to do that yourself

Comment: If you hard coded the URL in the script, of course it only works on one page.  You need to read up on variables generally and server variables (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) in particular

Comment: Bear in mind that HTTP_REFERRER is specified by the browser, and can be spoofed. In other words, do not rely on it for site security.

Comment: "this is a community to help developers, not to do your work for you. So either hire someone to do your work, or learn how to do that yourself"  I'm trying to learn, I've been searching for weeks, but I'm not a developer.  I didn't know this site was for developers only...  They probably shouldn't just let anyone log in with their google account, like I did, if it's not a community for anyone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than checking referer matches on one link:

```
if (($referer=="my url containing php script link")...
```

Create an array of links and match against that:

```
$referers = array('link1', 'link2','link3');
if((in_array($referer, $referers)...
```